# AWS Glue Filter Records from Source or Dynamic DataFrame

Tags: mysql, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I would like to retrieve a subset of records in an AWS Glue job from a MySQL table in a Data Catalog. This would be particularly helpful while developing a job script to limit the number of records that need to be processed.

My first attempt was to filter by an `id` column with a pushdown predicate. However I suspect that MySQL tables in a Data Catalog are not partitioned and don't support this feature. In python:

```py
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
dy_f = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="db",
    table_name="table with 1000 records",
    push_down_predicate="id in (1, 2, 3)"
)
dy_f.count() # returns 1000
```

Is there a way to limit the number of records retrieved from a MySQL table source? If not from the source, how can I filter a Dynamic Dataframe to a subset of records?

Comment: Are you trying to just do a random limit? If yes, you could try head().

Comment: Random would work well yes. Thanks! I'm also curious if there's a way to filter by some predicate.

Comment: props = {"driver":" pls replace with driver name "}
predicates = [
"DEST_COUNTRY_NAME = 'Sweden' OR ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME = 'Sweden'",
"DEST_COUNTRY_NAME = 'Anguilla' OR ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME = 'Anguilla'"]
spark.read.jdbc(url, tablename, predicates=predicates, properties=props).show()
spark.read.jdbc(url,tablename,predicates=predicates,properties=props).rdd.getNumPartitions()